# Switching to a different wireless network on a headless Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh, wireless

I am running a headless Raspberry Pi and I have multiple wireless networks at home. I SSH into my Pi. Is there a command line way to switch which network the Pi is on? Yes, I realize that I will lose the connection until after I reconnect to the new network.

Comment: Reputation too low to add a comment, so I have to use this route. I already have my wpa_supplicant set up with four networks. And the priority. The question is if I need to jump to the priority 2 network, how do I do that via command line?

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Which will enable you to edit the `wpa_supplicant file`. Add the following code to the bottom:

```
network={
    ssid="HomeOneSSID"
    psk="passwordOne"
    priority=1
    id_str="homeOne"
}

network={
    ssid="HomeTwoSSID"
    psk="passwordTwo"
    priority=2
    id_str="homeTwo"
}
```

Exit the file with saving. I suggest doing this for the different networks you intend to connect to. In the example code above the details for two different networks has been added.

Note also that the `priority` line determines which network is connected to in preference to another available network. This isn't necessary but might be useful in your case.

Next you need to run:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

And using the example networks from above add these lines to the bottom of the file:

```
iface homeOne inet dhcp
iface homeTwo inet dhcp
```

The finished file should look something like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface homeOne inet dhcp
iface homeTwo inet dhcp
```

Comment: This **MAY** work, but it will also break `dhcpcd`, preventing the networking icon on GUI from working (among other things). Have you actually tested it on a normal Raspbian installation?

Comment: I must confess I haven't, but this seems to be the way to do it by just using a command line interface. The fact it disables the GUI icon isn't great but the OP said in their question they only SSH into their Pi, so I wouldn't have thought that would have been an issue for them.